# What is the best way to generate a vector with equal number of random numbers in each block?

Tags: r, for-loop

Suppose I want to create a vector length of 10000 with random numbers of 1-4 of equal counts (also each number appears exact once in every 4 numbers with different ordering). I can use the following R code with a `for()` loop:

```
res <- NULL
for (i in 1:10000) {
   set.seed(i)
   res <- c(res, sample(1:4))
}
```

And I got

```
head(res, 20)
# [1] 2 4 3 1 1 3 2 4 1 3 4 2 3 1 4 2 1 3 2 4
```

Since the `for()` loop is generally not recommended in R, is there a fast way to achieve this?

Comment: For compact coding may be `c(replicate(10000, sample(1:4)))`, but it is also looping with `sapply`.  A properly executed `for` loop would be more or less similar in efficiency as an `apply` solution.

Comment: Thanks, @akrun. I think `replicate` function does the trick!

Comment: *the `for()` loop is generally not recommended in R* is a myth.  It depends on what you are doing.  There are many many cases where `for()` loops will be the best method

Comment: Thanks, @RichardScriven. Maybe I just didn't find an example where `for()` loop is the best.

Comment: Dig into some base R source code, you'll find one ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(combinat)
#create a matrix with all permutations of 1:4
perms <- do.call(rbind, permn(4))
set.seed(42)
n <- 20
#sample the permutations
choices <- sample(nrow(perms), n / 4, replace = TRUE)
res <- perms[choices,]
as.vector(t(res))
#[1] 2 4 1 3 2 1 4 3 1 3 4 2 4 2 3 1 3 2 1 4
```

Comment: If `n` is larger than 96, `sample(nrow(perms),n/4)` throws an error because there are only 24 permutations of {1,2,3,4}. To fix it, set `replace=TRUE`.

Comment: @mra68 Thanks. I forgot to add it.